# Is there a way to update the Colab Marketplace VM image to a newer version on a custom GCE instance?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Given a GCE VM with Colab installed via the Colab Marketplace VM image, is there a way to upgrade the image, while retaining all of the data on the machine? Or do you have to create a new instance with the latest Marketplace image and then move the data to the new VM?